# How to use localizations in SCEditor? (and general feedback & experiences)

Tags: javascript, sceditor

I'm currently evaluating javascript based BBCode editors for a project.
The [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/documentation/getting-started/) seems to be realy great and got a lot of usefull features.

But can anyone tell me how to use the localizations? I could not find any localization files so I don't know if there are any prebuild languages existing or if i have to create them for my own, and in this case, how they have to look like.
I also could not find any documentation for this, there is just this hint the [documentation](http://www.sceditor.com/documentation/options/#locale).

And in general:
How are your experiances with this editor? And are there any other suggestions i maybe should have a look at?

Comment: It seems you confused [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) with [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/), these are two different products.

Comment: @Dominik Did you mean SCEditor You have mentioned CKEditor in your title and description but linked to SCEditor. Please correct the question by clicking [edit].

Comment: Because OP's links go to SCEditor page and the product described (BBCode editor, no localization files, no localization documentation) do not refer to CKEditor which is an HTML WYSIWYG editor (with a proof-of-concept BBCode plugin available), with localization files visible in the build and localization documentation & samples easily available.

Comment: My bad sorry, i'm talking about SCEditor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the localization, that is actually all you need to do. Just include the correct `.js` localization file and that will be the localization that SCEditor will use for that webpage.

Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Forget about it, I'm blind! Please dont ask me how I could not see the folder "languages" in the download package -.-